# Class Not Returning Interface Instance PHP

Tags: php, class, interface

I'm getting a weird error on a class that implements an interface.

**Error:**

> Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   MyApp\Library\Cache::__construct()  must be an instance of
>   MyApp\Contacts\CacheInterface,  instance of MyApp\Driver\Cache\File
>   given

**File Class:**

```
namespace MyApp\Driver\Cache;
use MyApp\Library\Config;
use MyApp\Contracts\CacheInterface;

class File implements CacheInterface {
    private $expire;

    public function __construct($expire, Config $config) {
        $this->expire = $expire;
        $this->config = $config;

        ... more code
    }
}
```

**Cache Class:**

```
namespace MyApp\Library;
use MyApp\Contacts\CacheInterface;

final class Cache {

    private $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheInterface $cache) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    ... more methods
}
```

**Interface:**

```
namespace MyApp\Contracts;
interface CacheInterface {

    public function get($key);
    public function set($key, $value);
    public function delete($key);
    public function flush_cache();
}
```

Implemented as a service in a Pimple Container like so:

```
$this->data['cache'] = function ($data) {
    switch ($data['config_cache_type_id']):
        case 'apc':
            $driver = new Apc($data['cache.time'], $data['config']);
            break;
        case 'mem':
            $driver = new Mem($data['cache.time'], $data['config']);
            $driver->connect();
            break;
        case 'file':
        default:
            $driver = new File($data['cache.time'], $data['config']);
            break;
    endswitch;

    return new Cache($driver);
};
```

Of course the 4 Driver and Cache classes are included with the `use` keyword before the container class.

I can't see what I'm missing I've done several other contracts in exactly the same procedure. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes they do, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your File.class, can you try replacing:

```
use MyApp\Contracts\CacheInterface;
```

With

```
use MyApp\Contacts\CacheInterface;
```

And for your interface, use:

```
namespace MyApp\Contacts;
```

Comment: So it was a type ... geez I must have started at that for 30 minutes and still didn't see it. Thanks Dave.